# WinForms, MS chart, adding series from a numericUpDown

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a numericUpDown control which should ,based on the input, draw a straight line on my chart. The input should be only for the Y axis of my chart.
I can see the Tpoint added to Legend but the line is not drawn. What am I missing? I've already looked at the samples for Microsoft Chart Controls and still didn't figure out what's wrong.

```
private void numericSeries_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == 13) 
   {
      int s = (int)numericSeries.Value;
      Series series = chart2.Series.Add("Tpoint" + (chart2.Series.Count).ToString());
     series.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
     series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
     series.BorderWidth = 1;
     series.Color = Color.Blue;
     series.Points.AddY(s);
   }
}
```

EDIT Unfortunately i cant upload pictures.
http://i58.tinypic.com/25aqe4m.jpg

2.EDIT - the chart in the picture is a real time chart which represents PWM values from a DC motor (Y value) vs Datetime (X value). The line i want to draw should represent the Setpoint (reference) value i'm trying to achive. 
My X axis

```
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart2.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(chart2.Series[0].Points[0].XValue).AddSeconds(15).ToOADate();
```

Comment: The straight line should be vertical? Post a link of an image of what you're trying to achieve, and post code of how your chart is initialized.

Comment: The chart was draged'n'droped from the toolbox if thats what you mean?

Comment: Shouldn't you add a second point??

Comment: Already tried series.Points.AddXY(0,s); Doesn't work.

Comment: AddXY(0,s)? OK, that may be the starting point, but where shall the line go?? maybe (100,s) or whatever your series unit brings you to the endpoint you seek..Give full data for 1st and 2nd points!

Comment: I added some additional details. Actually the X value cant be zero beacause there would be no line at all, it would be a dot on the Y axis. I need a straight line meaning a single Y value for the whole time interval (x axis).

Comment: I assume you don't want __only__ one line..? To create a horizontal line you need either a (separate) series with two points eg (0:00,s) and (4:00, s) or a horizontalLineAnnotation. (These are a bit complicated to create but can easily be moved by the user..)

Comment: Yes, only one line. Two points ? As in series.points.addXY or something else?